# how use javascript in meta keyword

Tags: javascript, html, meta-tags

i have this cod in Html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test page</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="???">
</head>
<body>
    <p><a href="#">sampel1</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">sampel2</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">sampel3</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

can i replace javascript code with ???? in header  keyword to take link name for meta keyword? and print like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test page</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="sampel1,sampel2,sampel3">
</head>
<body>
    <p><a href="#">sampel1</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">sampel2</a></p>
    <p><a href="#/">sampel3</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't do that.  Consider using server-side code

Comment: just so you know, `keyword` meta tags are considered mostly useless

Comment: Not sure why you want to do this.. it has no effect at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set and change metadata after the DOM finishes loading, but unless you intend to read in the values using JavaScript, there is likely to be little benefit in doing so as the browser has already used any applicable metadata when the document initially loads, and Google is likely to pay no notice to any metadata set by Javascript.

Strongly consider using a server side solution, such as PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("meta[name='keywords']").attr("content", "sampel1,sampel2,sampel3");
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cgJx7/)

As it was said before, there is pretty much no point of doing this. A server-side solution would have to be used.